# Get row number result in correct order?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ranking-functions

I have a query to get JobRanking based on yearleftpost to get latest job followed by previous jobs worked.

```
select
    c.id,
    c.Fname,
    cfe.JobYear,
    cfe.YearLeftPost,
    cfe.Iscurrentjob,                                         
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by c.id ORDER BY Iscurrentjob DESC, yearleftpost DESC) AS JobRanking
from
candidates c
left join Candidate_FunctionalExperience cfe on c.id = cfe.CandidateID
```

It gives me the result:

```
id  Fname    JobYear  YearLeftPost  Iscurrentjob JobRanking
EC2 sdsadsa  1430     1433              1           1
EC2 sdsadsa  1429     1430              0           2
EC2 sdsadsa  1424     1428              0           3
EC2 sdsadsa  1428     1428              0           4
EC2 sdsadsa  1424     1426              0           5
```

Now, I have a IscurrentJob (Boolean value) 0 or 1, I am not getting the correct order of JobRanking.

Comment: Edit the question add full sample output, as your `SELECT` statement has `6` columns  but you display only `4` columns.

Comment: Reasons not to use images are [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/92546).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `Iscurrenjjob=1` rows to be first in the rankings then add that to your ordering clause:

```
Partition by c.id ORDER BY Iscurrentjob DESC, yearleftpost DESC
```

Comment: This gives me 2 JobRanking = 1 in the same result set.

Comment: @RKKK for the same id? You should have distinct ranks for each id based on the partition.

Comment: Thanks Stanley :) ,This works fine now I tried with both scenarios when there is no current job and with a current job value,

Comment: select
    c.id,
    c.Fname,
    cfe.JobYear,
    cfe.YearLeftPost,
    cfe.Iscurrentjob,                                         
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by c.id ORDER BY Iscurrentjob DESC, yearleftpost DESC) AS JobRanking
 from
 candidates c
 left join Candidate_FunctionalExperience cfe on c.id = cfe.CandidateID

Comment: This works but not in the scenario when the yearleftpost is same. This is possible when a job is only for few months but we don't have any month/day field for calculation

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job.

```
 select
    c.id,
    c.Fname,
    cfe.JobYear,
    cfe.YearLeftPost,
    cfe.Iscurrentjob,                                         
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by c.id) AS JobRanking
 from
 candidates c
 left join Candidate_FunctionalExperience cfe on c.id = cfe.CandidateID
 ORDER BY cfe.Iscurrentjob desc, cfe.YearLeftPost desc
```

Comment: Edited the question but the ranking is still wrong when the date of Yearleftpost are same

Comment: Hi @RKKK please show us how do you want it to be ? Thanks!

Comment: I have updated my answer ... but on blind, without info I asked. Please try it and comment what you would like for order by to be ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With conditional sorting:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
  Partition by c.id 
  ORDER BY CASE WHEN cfe.Iscurrentjob = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, yearleftpost DESC
) AS JobRanking
```

Comment: Edited the question but the ranking is still wrong when the date of Yearleftpost are same

Comment: Post sample data and expected results for each scenario to clarify.